# Why does switching from constraint-layout-1.0.2 to 1.1.3 break my custom toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

We have an Android app with some Activities that share a toolbar.  Everything was working well, until I (at Android Studio's recommendation) switched my build.gradle file from constraint-layout:1.0.2 to 1.1.3.  Now the toolbar covers the entire visible screen.  I'm unsure why this happened or how to fix it.  My current workaround is to go back to 1.0.2.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is the build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation project(':pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release')
    implementation project(':models')
    implementation 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:4.2.1'
    implementation ('net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.2.2')
    implementation 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.9.1'
    implementation project(':ibm-library')
    implementation project(':annotations')
    implementation files('../../../../lib/findBugs-2.0.2/annotations.jar')
    annotationProcessor project(':annotations')
    implementation project(':falcon') // Supports screenshots

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // We use Mockito because it doesn't need extra code to mock final methods and classes.
    // JMock could work, if DexOpener worked (like JDave-Unfinalizer, but for DEX files), but
    // I was unable to make it work.  Hence I switched to Mockito, which is the favorite among Android
    // Developers (SMM)
//    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
//    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.4/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.4/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../nb/ORCCommon/dist/ORCCommon-test.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../nb/CommonLibrary/dist/CommonLibrary-test.jar')
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs' // We already have findbugs
    })
}
```

Here is the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.hcs.android.orconnect.ui.widget.ORConnectToolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

</com.hcs.android.orconnect.ui.widget.ORConnectToolbar>
```

Here is the toolbar code:

```
package com.hcs.android.orconnect.ui.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hcs.android.orconnect.ORConnectApplication;
import com.hcs.android.orconnect.R;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Custom toolbar, that also serves as our "red bar" much like the downTimePanel in FullScreenFrame in ORC.
 */
public class ORConnectToolbar extends Toolbar {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.hcs.android.orconnect.ui.widget.ORConnectToolbar");
    /** The old title when we've changed the title for something like a connection failure. */
    private CharSequence defaultTitle;
    /** The default background color. */
    private int defaultBackgroundColor;
    /** True if we are showing a connection failure. */
    private boolean redBarVisible = false;
    /** Keep this so we only create one and clean up after ourselves. */
    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener = null;

    public ORConnectToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ORConnectToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ORConnectToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if(layoutListener != null) {
            TextView titleView = getActionBarTextView();
            if (titleView != null) {
                ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = titleView.getViewTreeObserver();
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
                layoutListener = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int resId) {
        setTitle(getContext().getText(resId));
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        super.setTitle(title);
        // Since the layout listener is going to shrink things, but not make them bigger, we on every
        // title change, we reset the font.
        setTitleTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.TextAppearance_Widget_Event_Toolbar_Title);
        // If we do not have a layout listener to adjust the text size to avoid ellipsis
        if(layoutListener == null) {
            // This is hacky, but Android doesn't provide us another way to get the Title Text View so we can listen to it.  Thanks, Google!
            TextView titleView = getActionBarTextView();
            if (titleView != null) {
                ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = titleView.getViewTreeObserver();
                layoutListener = () -> {
                    // Do we have ellipses on the end of our title?  Very bad, Google!  Shrink to fit!
                    Layout layout = titleView.getLayout();
                    if (layout != null) {
                        int lines = layout.getLineCount();
                        if (layout.getEllipsisCount(lines) > 0) {
                            // Yes, we have ellipsis, grrr...
                            float currentSize = titleView.getTextSize() / titleView.getPaint().density; // Google, won't let us get the scaled pixels, so we have to do the scaling ourselves... really guys!
                            titleView.setTextSize(currentSize - 2);
                        }
                    }
                };
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Google forgot to make the titleTextView protected so we could do things with it.  So, we use
     * reflection to work around that (yuck!).
     *
     * Thanks Google!
     * @return the title text view, if we were able to get it.
     */
    private TextView getActionBarTextView() {
        TextView titleTextView = null;
        try {
            Field f = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            titleTextView = (TextView) f.get(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to get Toolbar Title TextView by reflection.  Shrink to fit may not work!", e);
        }
        return titleTextView;
    }
}
```

Finally, an activity that is showing the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/> <!-- Bring the tool bar in -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textSize="90sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:ignore="UnknownId,UnknownIdInLayout"
        tools:text="Loading..." />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the toolbar's `layout_height` value to `?attr/actionBarSize` and delete the `android:minHeight` attribute?

Comment: Set app:layout_constrainedHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" and removed minHeight with no change.  The toolbar still consumes everything.

Comment: I meant `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`, not `app:layout_constrainedHeight`. You've currently got it set to `match_parent`, which (a) ConstraintLayout does not support (though sometimes it does "work") and (b) would make it fill the screen in cases where it _does_ work.

Comment: @BenP. That worked!  Thank you for the explanation.  If you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of your toolbar from `match_parent` to `?attr/actionBarSize`:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Additionally, delete this attribute as it doesn't have any effect:

> ```
> android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize
> ```

---

Note that `ConstraintLayout` does not support `match_parent` for its children. If you want "match parent" behavior, you should combine a dimension of `0dp` with left+right or top+bottom constraints to the parent.

However, even though `ConstraintLayout` doesn't officially support `match_parent`, it **does** sometimes "work". This will change from version to version, from build to build, etc. So probably your old version was ignoring it but the new version was not ignoring it (and therefore your toolbar was filling the screen).